# PowerShell Create Hashtable if doesn't exist and add values

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm taking a manually created hashtable so I can iterate over

```
$aceList = @{
    "Domain\jdoe" = "Change, Submit, GetPassword"
    "Domain\ssmith" = "Change, Submit, GetPassword"
    "Domain\msmith" = "Submit"
}
```

However this doesn't allow me to abstract it more.

Ideally what I would like is something like this without having to set the `$acl = @{}` outside of the function?

```
function Set-HashTable {
    Param(
        [String]$Identity,
        [String]$Access,
        [Hashtable]$ACL
    )
    $ACL.Add($Identity, $Access)
    return $ACL
}

$acl = @{}
$acl = Set-ACL -Identity "Domain\jdoe" -Access "Change, Submit, GetPassword" -ACL $acl
$acl = Set-ACL -Identity "Domain\ssmith" -Access "Change, Submit, GetPassword" -ACL $acl
$acl = Set-ACL -Identity "Domain\msmith" -Access "Submit" -ACL $acl
```

Comment: have you tried adding an in-function test to see if the hashtable already exists? [*grin*]

Comment: Ya I just did that all I need to do is ensure I clear the hashtable later to avoid overloading it.

Comment: that sounds like you are just swapping "make it 1st" for "clear it last". [*grin*] i suspect i would had a `New-AclTable` and an `Add-ToAclTalbe` ... or just do it without any function at all.

Comment: `[Hashtable]$ACL` -> `[Hashtable]$ACL = @{}`

Comment: BTW, I suppose `Set-ACL` in your code snippet is actually supposed to be `Set-HashTable`? Because you shouldn't re-define builtin cmdlets.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Set-ACL is a builtin?  If so yes I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parameter `$ACL` a default value and you can avoid passing the initial empty hashtable:

```
function Set-HashTable {
    Param(
        [String]$Identity,
        [String]$Access,
        [Hashtable]$ACL = @{}
    )
    $ACL.Add($Identity, $Access)
    return $ACL
}

$acl = Set-HashTable -Identity 'Domain\jdoe' -Access 'Change, Submit, GetPassword'
$acl = Set-HashTable -Identity 'Domain\ssmith' -Access 'Change, Submit, GetPassword' -ACL $acl
$acl = Set-HashTable -Identity 'Domain\msmith' -Access 'Submit' -ACL $acl
```

With that said, I don't see the advantage of encapsulating an operation like adding key/value pairs to a hashtable in a function. Doing it directly is far more straightforward, like this:

```
$acl = @{}
$acl.Add('Domain\jdoe', 'Change, Submit, GetPassword')
$acl.Add('Domain\ssmith', 'Change, Submit, GetPassword')
$acl.Add('Domain\msmith', 'Submit')
```

or like this:

```
$acl = @{}
$acl['Domain\jdoe']   = 'Change, Submit, GetPassword'
$acl['Domain\ssmith'] = 'Change, Submit, GetPassword'
$acl['Domain\msmith'] = 'Submit'
```